# Asp.net mvc 3 dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, dependency-injection

I'm a bit confused with DI and IoC. I have set up MVC and I use Ninject for properties injection and it works perfectly. My application is set to use Portable Areas from MvcContrib and each area is contained from providers, services, models and controllers.

Providers from one area can access other providers in same or sub assemblies. To resolve dependency in provider I use DependencyResolver.Cur... which is registered to use Ninject as well. I would like to know if this is a good approach since I don't want to pass all other providers from controllers to last layer, but I want to access them directly from provider. Should I create an instance of kernel in lowest assembly like Core so I can access it directly from anywhere?

Thnx in advance

UPDATE:
I would also want to know if it is possible to use property injection in normal class.

Comment: What do you mean by "good approach?"  What is your requirement that needs to succeed for you to declare success?

Comment: My primary concern is object lifecycle, since some of the objects are fairly expensive to load its very important that objects are reused as much as possible. And second is simplicity for maintenance and upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you design all your services (reposities, application services, controllers, etc) around the *constructor injection pattern*, there is no need to call `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` from within a class and there is no need to make an instance of the kernel available in the lowest assembly.

When all your services use constructor injection, your container will be able to construct an object graph of dependent services when a root type is requested: in your case a controller class. When you do this, no code needs to access the `DependencyResolver` or the `Kernel` directly, which ensures your code will be more testable, flexible, and maintainable. Any code that accesses the `DependencyResolver` or static `Kernel` instance is hard to test, hides its dependencies, and makes it difficult to verify the container's configuration in an automated fashion.

Instead of using *constructor injection*, you can achieve the same with *property injection*. However, since the convention is that properties are for optional dependencies, Ninject (and any other container) will skip a property it can't inject (implicit property injection), instead of throwing an exception, as would happen with a missing constructor argument dependency. This again makes it much harder to find configuration errors in your application. So, whenever possible, stick with constructor injection.

Comment: Thank you very much for elaborate explanation. One more smaller question, can I use automated constructor injection in any other form other than in controller, since controller is handled by controller factory, can I build my own factory for elements that are not handled by controllers

Comment: Absolutely. Your container will build the dependency graph recursively. This means that when a controller is requested, it will inject its dependencies and the dependencies of those dependencies. Let your services have a single public constructor that contains all (required) dependencies. This makes life so much easier.